# Including lagged independent variables - R

Tags: r, time-series, regression, linear-regression

I would like to run a regression where I use both the current value and lagged values from a specific independent variable.

**My dataset**

This is an example extract from my dataset:

```
dt          nrOfCalls nrOfOrders nrOfOrdersLag1 nrOfOrdersLag2 nrOfOrdersLag3
2016/04/20  17        5          9              7              12
2016/04/21  12        8          5              9              7
2016/04/22  14        4          8              5              9
2016/04/23  15        6          4              8              5
2016/04/24  20        14         6              4              8
2016/04/25  10        3          14             6              4
```

Where NrOfOrdersLag*X* implies the number of orders *X* days ago. I have also included dummy variables (because of limited space I have included these dummy variables in the example extract of my dataset).

**My code**

When I run the following code everything works perfectly fine:

```
reg <- lm(nrOfCalls ~ dummy1+...+dummy6+nrOfOrders, data=trainingSet)
```

However, when I try including the lagged values of the nrOfOrders regressor (for this example I only include one lagged value), I get some inordinary results. I use the following code:

```
reg <- lm(nrOfCalls ~ dummy1+...+dummy6+nrOfOrders+nrOfOrdersLag1, data=trainingSet)
```

Instead of merely including the regressor nrOfOrdersLag1, it will include all kinds of regressors which variable names are a variation on nrOfOrdersLag1.

```
Call:
lm(formula = nrOfCalls ~ dummy1 + dummy2 + dummy3 + dummy4 + 
    dummy5 + dummy6 + nrOfOrders + nrOfOrdersLag1, data = trainCall)

Coefficients:
        (Intercept)               dummy1               dummy2               dummy3               dummy4  
          604.06334           -114.03241           -229.67540           -270.62292           -220.12409  
             dummy5               dummy6           nrOfOrders  nrOfOrdersLag110707   nrOfOrdersLag11161  
         -457.22245           -465.17116              0.01729           -249.54641            -10.98526  
nrOfOrdersLag111869   nrOfOrdersLag11207   nrOfOrdersLag11234   nrOfOrdersLag11262   nrOfOrdersLag11267  
           45.36821             33.46161            -17.70615           -384.09745           -413.64804  
 nrOfOrdersLag11279   nrOfOrdersLag11285  nrOfOrdersLag112945   nrOfOrdersLag11336   nrOfOrdersLag11348  
         -200.19660             32.75546           -264.04005            -47.13457             79.48368  
 nrOfOrdersLag11351   nrOfOrdersLag11355   nrOfOrdersLag11363   nrOfOrdersLag11364   nrOfOrdersLag11368  
         -208.62312              6.83426            -98.71679            170.29583            -93.83054  
 nrOfOrdersLag11375   nrOfOrdersLag11398   nrOfOrdersLag11456   nrOfOrdersLag11462   nrOfOrdersLag11464  
           50.54960             14.39958            118.73762            113.72744            190.54445  
 nrOfOrdersLag11469  nrOfOrdersLag114778   nrOfOrdersLag11486   nrOfOrdersLag11489   nrOfOrdersLag11504  
           -8.79258             84.35041             66.29121             29.67360             24.30553  
 nrOfOrdersLag11505   nrOfOrdersLag11511   nrOfOrdersLag11520   nrOfOrdersLag11521   nrOfOrdersLag11527  
          286.85352             69.76762           -159.45588            -38.90402             53.62128  
 nrOfOrdersLag11538   nrOfOrdersLag11540   nrOfOrdersLag11564  nrOfOrdersLag115674   nrOfOrdersLag11579  
         -104.66037            -60.10656            -58.32177            522.56810             77.65481  
 nrOfOrdersLag11587   nrOfOrdersLag11593   nrOfOrdersLag11603   nrOfOrdersLag11618   nrOfOrdersLag11622  
           34.63649             31.28570           -124.35673             16.43115            207.99435  
 nrOfOrdersLag11624   nrOfOrdersLag11626   nrOfOrdersLag11629   nrOfOrdersLag11631   nrOfOrdersLag11635  
           93.90391             78.94275            155.88327             15.32027            125.02409  
 nrOfOrdersLag11640   nrOfOrdersLag11645   nrOfOrdersLag11649   nrOfOrdersLag11651   nrOfOrdersLag11653  
          208.51996            -42.03086             -1.62533            164.73045             12.61157  
 nrOfOrdersLag11654   nrOfOrdersLag11673   nrOfOrdersLag11683   nrOfOrdersLag11688   nrOfOrdersLag11698  
          129.26306            -41.56615            137.09095            149.86866            -49.43096  
 nrOfOrdersLag11699   nrOfOrdersLag11702   nrOfOrdersLag11703   nrOfOrdersLag11705   nrOfOrdersLag11714  
           76.86530            202.69027            -70.26281           -173.43605            170.02302  
 nrOfOrdersLag11715   nrOfOrdersLag11716   nrOfOrdersLag11726   nrOfOrdersLag11749   nrOfOrdersLag11754  
           34.30252             75.45378            176.16211             76.39492             58.11995  
 nrOfOrdersLag11757   nrOfOrdersLag11764   nrOfOrdersLag11766   nrOfOrdersLag11772   nrOfOrdersLag11777  
          133.71731            137.62373             24.95059            -75.96096             54.03353  
 nrOfOrdersLag11778   nrOfOrdersLag11782   nrOfOrdersLag11793   nrOfOrdersLag11806   nrOfOrdersLag11810  
         -147.40657            -45.70752             27.76710             94.17449           -191.98461  
 nrOfOrdersLag11811   nrOfOrdersLag11812   nrOfOrdersLag11814   nrOfOrdersLag11815   nrOfOrdersLag11817  
           61.04646            145.25908             38.56959             18.22574            140.84081  
 nrOfOrdersLag11827   nrOfOrdersLag11832   nrOfOrdersLag11839   nrOfOrdersLag11841   nrOfOrdersLag11859  
         -254.56931            138.30797           -139.32523           -151.50010             39.27760  
 nrOfOrdersLag11860   nrOfOrdersLag11862   nrOfOrdersLag11868   nrOfOrdersLag11874   nrOfOrdersLag11876  
          304.88804            150.84361             30.75749            -91.55666            192.43385  
 nrOfOrdersLag11879   nrOfOrdersLag11880   nrOfOrdersLag11885   nrOfOrdersLag11887   nrOfOrdersLag11891  
          118.75260            -44.83615            163.35474            194.12038            127.79107  
 nrOfOrdersLag11896   nrOfOrdersLag11901   nrOfOrdersLag11914   nrOfOrdersLag11919   nrOfOrdersLag11921  
           82.79870            179.44324            303.18796            242.51540            159.40652  
 nrOfOrdersLag11928   nrOfOrdersLag11929   nrOfOrdersLag11932   nrOfOrdersLag11937   nrOfOrdersLag11939  
          484.73958             35.38640            286.54643             46.88513             48.94031  
 nrOfOrdersLag11952   nrOfOrdersLag11967   nrOfOrdersLag11988   nrOfOrdersLag11994   nrOfOrdersLag11996  
          265.02228            170.65576             47.77627            317.10968            383.09702  
nrOfOrdersLag119987   nrOfOrdersLag12007   nrOfOrdersLag12010   nrOfOrdersLag12017   nrOfOrdersLag12018  
          416.71786             93.41540             61.71721             73.68938            136.60641  
 nrOfOrdersLag12019   nrOfOrdersLag12023   nrOfOrdersLag12027   nrOfOrdersLag12034   nrOfOrdersLag12040  
           88.13672           -214.93168             38.82154            148.72993            -60.63852  
 nrOfOrdersLag12050   nrOfOrdersLag12051   nrOfOrdersLag12056   nrOfOrdersLag12058   nrOfOrdersLag12060  
          205.21811            246.46001            163.20151             -0.35863             61.93024  
 nrOfOrdersLag12073   nrOfOrdersLag12082   nrOfOrdersLag12087   nrOfOrdersLag12093   nrOfOrdersLag12107  
          122.50936            -27.13307            -43.74262            366.51938            146.85581  
 nrOfOrdersLag12119   nrOfOrdersLag12122   nrOfOrdersLag12124  nrOfOrdersLag121319   nrOfOrdersLag12133  
          119.31341             36.35183            253.68015            115.01838            228.66567  
 nrOfOrdersLag12136   nrOfOrdersLag12137   nrOfOrdersLag12154   nrOfOrdersLag12167   nrOfOrdersLag12169  
           -9.97711            121.20416           -448.43096            324.45466            169.37446  
 nrOfOrdersLag12176   nrOfOrdersLag12180   nrOfOrdersLag12181   nrOfOrdersLag12184   nrOfOrdersLag12186  
           88.35432            -14.74399             41.03555            310.68640            308.82549  
 nrOfOrdersLag12189   nrOfOrdersLag12195   nrOfOrdersLag12202   nrOfOrdersLag12204   nrOfOrdersLag12216  
          121.87542            264.78895            191.52156            281.02113            168.29821  
 nrOfOrdersLag12219   nrOfOrdersLag12221   nrOfOrdersLag12231   nrOfOrdersLag12236   nrOfOrdersLag12237  
          218.48030             66.07233           -228.54230            111.06068            162.65347  
 nrOfOrdersLag12242   nrOfOrdersLag12244   nrOfOrdersLag12246   nrOfOrdersLag12261   nrOfOrdersLag12262  
           12.05505            114.60872           -123.06406            -45.54485            380.26022  
 nrOfOrdersLag12268   nrOfOrdersLag12271   nrOfOrdersLag12302   nrOfOrdersLag12304   nrOfOrdersLag12311  
            4.23556            249.55941            248.38079            103.12194            -71.69000  
 nrOfOrdersLag12313   nrOfOrdersLag12329   nrOfOrdersLag12345   nrOfOrdersLag12353   nrOfOrdersLag12356  
          247.93662            207.13958            314.96154             95.08688            300.10247  
 nrOfOrdersLag12361   nrOfOrdersLag12371   nrOfOrdersLag12376   nrOfOrdersLag12380   nrOfOrdersLag12384  
           37.27506           -167.84137             66.61313            247.32681            237.73556  
 nrOfOrdersLag12399   nrOfOrdersLag12406   nrOfOrdersLag12413   nrOfOrdersLag12417   nrOfOrdersLag12420  
          107.37362            399.28658            275.48695             95.07723            324.87029  
 nrOfOrdersLag12423   nrOfOrdersLag12434   nrOfOrdersLag12437   nrOfOrdersLag12442   nrOfOrdersLag12446  
          233.30480            193.45613            250.79606            322.78975            320.40151  
 nrOfOrdersLag12448   nrOfOrdersLag12449   nrOfOrdersLag12451   nrOfOrdersLag12460  nrOfOrdersLag124708  
          172.20478           -113.45790            108.52769            305.32173           -134.41931  
 nrOfOrdersLag12484   nrOfOrdersLag12486   nrOfOrdersLag12493   nrOfOrdersLag12497   nrOfOrdersLag12505  
          156.35931             -9.49808            223.13247            -67.47891            534.66815  
 nrOfOrdersLag12541   nrOfOrdersLag12552   nrOfOrdersLag12563   nrOfOrdersLag12588   nrOfOrdersLag12596  
          221.35464              1.92188            -53.40846           -473.89923            497.69016  
 nrOfOrdersLag12611   nrOfOrdersLag12618   nrOfOrdersLag12623   nrOfOrdersLag12632   nrOfOrdersLag12638  
          175.77150            125.22040           -302.58298           -159.54109           -337.04664  
 nrOfOrdersLag12646   nrOfOrdersLag12648   nrOfOrdersLag12663   nrOfOrdersLag12665   nrOfOrdersLag12687  
          539.15416            350.53169           -148.22458            147.67351           -349.52567  
 nrOfOrdersLag12696   nrOfOrdersLag12713   nrOfOrdersLag12721   nrOfOrdersLag12723   nrOfOrdersLag12743  
          -42.64843            141.90979             47.07766           -443.50878            356.28944  
 nrOfOrdersLag12745   nrOfOrdersLag12750   nrOfOrdersLag12753   nrOfOrdersLag12761  nrOfOrdersLag127688  
           14.65720             13.35666              8.30924           -191.17540           -123.52409  
 nrOfOrdersLag12802   nrOfOrdersLag12806   nrOfOrdersLag12812   nrOfOrdersLag12815   nrOfOrdersLag12818  
          128.14604            281.35157            361.79299              8.34690             86.67458  
 nrOfOrdersLag12824   nrOfOrdersLag12836   nrOfOrdersLag12841   nrOfOrdersLag12842   nrOfOrdersLag12876  
          518.23720           -357.78788            288.63660            433.15556            158.51341  
 nrOfOrdersLag12883   nrOfOrdersLag12884   nrOfOrdersLag12901   nrOfOrdersLag12941   nrOfOrdersLag12956  
          214.74913             68.99485           -208.43888           -297.43011            319.30849  
 nrOfOrdersLag12996   nrOfOrdersLag13007   nrOfOrdersLag13013   nrOfOrdersLag13023   nrOfOrdersLag13033  
          321.02569            -88.96746             80.93579            106.97804           -223.88599  
 nrOfOrdersLag13051   nrOfOrdersLag13072   nrOfOrdersLag13094   nrOfOrdersLag13098   nrOfOrdersLag13127  
           40.95339            161.48086            524.04025            -94.23016             17.50082  
 nrOfOrdersLag13152   nrOfOrdersLag13171   nrOfOrdersLag13185   nrOfOrdersLag13202   nrOfOrdersLag13205  
         -266.11135              8.82232           -107.11441           -141.14442            212.80057  
 nrOfOrdersLag13222   nrOfOrdersLag13277   nrOfOrdersLag13295   nrOfOrdersLag13321   nrOfOrdersLag13332  
          187.90431            306.69183            -24.55235             68.42339           -290.11682  
 nrOfOrdersLag13362   nrOfOrdersLag13378   nrOfOrdersLag13380   nrOfOrdersLag13391   nrOfOrdersLag13476  
           44.30976            463.85118            276.57882           -282.06457             34.35207  
 nrOfOrdersLag13488   nrOfOrdersLag13490   nrOfOrdersLag13530   nrOfOrdersLag13578   nrOfOrdersLag13599  
          217.46608            386.26006            194.69082             52.45357            406.44931  
 nrOfOrdersLag13611   nrOfOrdersLag13618   nrOfOrdersLag13626   nrOfOrdersLag13632   nrOfOrdersLag13635  
          242.81201            -22.19253             23.90163           -395.87751            103.44677  
 nrOfOrdersLag13674   nrOfOrdersLag13681   nrOfOrdersLag13767   nrOfOrdersLag13841   nrOfOrdersLag13849  
          200.18354             83.25027            -71.88190            382.05886           -279.73606  
 nrOfOrdersLag13857   nrOfOrdersLag13874   nrOfOrdersLag13885   nrOfOrdersLag13897   nrOfOrdersLag13908  
          370.92867            -17.14313           -140.99009           -244.17716             93.79552  
 nrOfOrdersLag13966   nrOfOrdersLag14009   nrOfOrdersLag14031   nrOfOrdersLag14111   nrOfOrdersLag14160  
           61.75484            224.96558           -107.99394           -126.12766            572.14222  
 nrOfOrdersLag14171   nrOfOrdersLag14205   nrOfOrdersLag14312   nrOfOrdersLag14468   nrOfOrdersLag14560  
          -42.29929           -379.41067            194.25204            -47.50642           -116.49251  
 nrOfOrdersLag14619   nrOfOrdersLag14640   nrOfOrdersLag14684   nrOfOrdersLag14762   nrOfOrdersLag14776  
           41.34325           -355.84333           -122.77109           -331.12296            404.86637  
 nrOfOrdersLag14865   nrOfOrdersLag14959   nrOfOrdersLag14967   nrOfOrdersLag15195   nrOfOrdersLag15218  
          371.14617            104.60840            -42.74014             99.78008            520.62517  
 nrOfOrdersLag15402   nrOfOrdersLag16029   nrOfOrdersLag16284   nrOfOrdersLag16321   nrOfOrdersLag16350  
          529.17004            161.02870            268.77256             74.02159            386.53868  
 nrOfOrdersLag16418   nrOfOrdersLag16557   nrOfOrdersLag16711   nrOfOrdersLag16722   nrOfOrdersLag16825  
          -81.37023            190.74905            225.64313           -131.70051            271.39936  
 nrOfOrdersLag16952   nrOfOrdersLag16996   nrOfOrdersLag17098   nrOfOrdersLag17251   nrOfOrdersLag17279  
          357.39158            408.46849            210.03477            -25.74894                   NA  
 nrOfOrdersLag17292   nrOfOrdersLag17391   nrOfOrdersLag18642   nrOfOrdersLag18670   nrOfOrdersLag18949  
          262.00528              4.71906            326.28857             49.30983            174.99732  
 nrOfOrdersLag19202   nrOfOrdersLag19690   nrOfOrdersLag19772  
           16.13322             15.59552            -62.26111
```

**I have no clue what is happening and why this is going wrong. Anybody that can help me out here? Thanks in advance!**

Comment: I think it is a typo: take a look at your formula: `nrOfCalls ~ dummy1+...+dummy6+nrOfOrders+nrOfOrdersLag1+` there is a trailing `+`. Your regression will probably work if you remove it.

Comment: @lmo Even though it would be fantastic if this is the only mistake, I am afraid that it is a typo from my side when copying the code to StackOverflow. In my R console I have made the call without the typo.

Comment: If there is any autocorrelation in this variable (which I would suspect) you would have strong issues of multicollinearity with this approach.

Comment: @Roland, I do agree with you on the autocorrelation point. It is something I work on in a later stage. I first had to get the *lm* call working, and this did not fail due to multicollinearity.

Answer (score 0):

The lagged independent variables were factor variables instead of integer/numeric variables. Having fixed this, the *lm* call works as intended.